# openssl_public_encrypt worked , but openssl_public_decrypt failed

Tags: php, rsa, public-key

I got a public key and a message,

```
    $msg = "blablabla";
    $public = '-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
     (some normal public key)
    -----END PUBLIC KEY-----';
```

the RsaEncode can encrypt

I do the RSA Encode the message

```
function RsaEncode($msg,$publicKey){
  $temp = str_split($msg,117);
  $payload = array();
  foreach ($temp as $key => $value) {
    openssl_public_encrypt($value, $encrypted, $publicKey);
    array_push($payload, $encrypted);
  }
  $payload =implode($payload);
   $payload= base64_encode($payload);
  return $payload;
}
```

This function return is OK, I encode the message successfully, 
after I sent the result , I got a response $response that encrypt with private key.

so I decode it with public key:

```
function RsaDecode($response,$publicKey){
 $payload = array();
 $payload2 = base64_decode($response);
 $temp = str_split($payload2,125);
 foreach ($temp as $key => $value) {
   openssl_public_decrypt($value, $encrypted, $publicKey);
   array_push($payload, $encrypted);
 }
 $payload =implode($payload);
 $result = utf8_encode($payload);
 return $result;
}
```

the $publicKey is the same $publicKey ,

the statement :

```
openssl_public_decrypt($value, $encrypted, $publicKey);
```

always return false.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I solve it after i change

```
$temp = str_split($payload2,125);
```

to

```
$temp = str_split($payload2,128);
```

the size can't too small